# get selected values of MultiSelect Picklist in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have multiselect picklist and I want to get selected values for insert and update operation.

```
<apex:page standardController="Change_Request__c" sidebar="false" extensions="Change_RequestController"> 
  <apex:selectList label="Select Pasenger(s)" value="{!Change_Request__c.Passenger_Name__c}" multiselect="true" onfocus="getSelectedID('{!$Component.empid}');" >
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!pax}" />
  </apex:selectList>
```

And this is my extension:

```
public class Change_RequestController {
  private final Change_Request__c changer;
  public List<selectOption> pax;
  public Change_RequestController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.changer = (Change_Request__c)controller.getRecord();
  }
  public List<selectOption> getPax() {
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    String fullName;
    for (Passenger_Info__c p : [SELECT Id,First_Name__c,Name  from Passenger_Info__c ]) {
      fullName = (p.First_Name__c == null)?'':p.First_Name__c+' '+p.Name; 
      options.add(new selectOption(fullName, fullName));
     }
     return options;
  }
  public List<selectOption> setPax() {
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    for (String pa : changer.Passenger_Name__c.split(',') ) {
      options.add(new selectOption(pa, pa));
     }
     return options;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change controler to

```
public class Change_RequestController {
  public Change_Request__c changer{get;set;}
  public Change_RequestController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.changer = (Change_Request__c)controller.getRecord();
  }
  public List<selectOption> getPax() {
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    String fullName;
    for (Passenger_Info__c p : [SELECT Id,First_Name__c,Name  from Passenger_Info__c ]) {
      fullName = (p.First_Name__c == null)?'':p.First_Name__c+' '+p.Name; 
      options.add(new selectOption(fullName, fullName));
     }
     return options;
  }
}
```

and page to

```
<apex:selectList label="Select Pasenger(s)" value="{!changer.Passenger_Name__c}" multiselect="true" onfocus="getSelectedID('{!$Component.empid}');" >
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!pax}" />
  </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: the controller is accepting the change but the visualpage said: Error: Unknown property 'Change_Request__cStandardController.changer'

Comment: So I did it, and i got this error: Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Change_Request__c.Passenger_Name__c  


So I add this line before the this.changer = (Change...

controller.addFields(new String[] {'Passenger_Name__c'});

The error is gone but the options still not selected